# How to set current on a cvcc?

Tags: buck, boost, basic

I got a cheapo cvcc off [ebay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/325665931162).

Setting volts is pretty easy. I just hook my multimeter leads to the output and twist.

But, how do I set amps? I need something to dump the current in. What should I dump that current in? The battery I'm charging, but what if the battery is already full? A power resistor? What should I use to set the correct amps?

Feel free to edit this question btw.

Comment: I think it uses one pot for current and another pot for voltage. It uses a pretty basic system, but does have a badic current limiting feature.

Answer (score 2):

For some designs, there's a warning not to short circuit the output pins.
Those, you'd use a current limiting resistor in series with an
ammeter, as a 'safe' load.   My adjustable power supply tolerates
shorts, so I just... short circuit the output with an ammeter to set current limit.

For instance, to set 4V and 300 mA to charge a lithium ion cell,
apply the voltmeter and set 4V, then connect an ammeter (which  is
a near-short-circuit) in series with a limiting resistor, such as
ten ohms.   As long as the resistor can draw MORE current than 300 mA,
you can then adjust the current-control potentiometer until the
reading hits your target (300 mA).

The resistor selected should satisfy the equation

$$V_{target} > I_{target} \times R$$

and, of course, should have a power rating no less than

$$V_{target} ^2  / R  $$

but the value is not critical.   A light bulb might be a good
load resistance.

It is good practice to voltage-probe the output while the load-and-ammeter
is applied, to be sure the two controls are acting independently, but a
well-designed unit should still obey your 4V setting while adjusting
the current control.